# home inspection for a condo

Tags: inspection

I am trying to purchase a condo in a three-story building. The condo is located at the third floor. During the home inspection, I would like to know what are the issues that I should pay attention to. Are there any specific items need to be carefully examined for a condo? What are the difference between inspecting a condo and inspecting a single family house? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having a home inspector do the inspection? if so make sure they are certified. Look for any signs of moisture stains, settling cracks (its common for there to be minor cracks depending on your location and materials used. Drywall at vaulted ceilings expand and contract naturally to temperature, but at tape lines) Most condo's and townhomes have an association that are typically responsible for the concrete, exterior and roof.  Just make sure you know what you are responsible for. Test all plumbing fixtures, let the water run for a while to expose any leaks.  Test outlets with an outlet tester.  IF you have any concerns make sure you kick them back to the seller for further disclosure. It's always smart to document. The inspector will probably not talk a whole lot about things that are cosmetic. Make sure they check all appliances, HVAC system and electrical panel. Attic will tell you of any moisture concerns and  inform you on the amount of insulation.